# 18.04.4 lts 32-bit intel system cannot unlock encrypted luks root filesystem after upgrade to 5.4.0-42 HWE kernel from 5.3.0-62

Tags: 18.04, kernel, encryption

18.04.4 lts 32-bit intel system cannot unlock encrypted luks root filesystem after upgrade to 5.4.0-42 HWE kernel from 5.3.0-62.
reverting to 5.3.0-62 encryption makes the password work again.
Need help.
This root encryption setup has worked for me since 12.04 lts.

Comment: FYI:  Your description detail should provide all details in the heading (some devices cannot display the heading at the same time message is open due to browser/screen-size, and your description text doesn't include your problem)